# In-app browser won't close

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, inappbrowser

I've took a different approach to creating an in-app browser and there still is no way for the user to return to the app. I had the same problem on my last approach. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? There should be a bar with a return button to take the user back to the app.

**HTML**:

```
<img class="brandHeight" type="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.youtube.com', '_blank', 'location=yes','closebuttoncaption=back'); return true;" ng-src="img/sb-my-inbox-table/sb-table-brand5.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

just use following code in onclick() action... :-

For a New Window :- `window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank");`
For a System Window :- `window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_system");`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/"></iframe>
```

Use JavaScript to show the iframe when the user clicks the `img`.

Comment: Thats not what I want

Answer (score 0):

- Which cordova version are you using?
- On which platform (OS) are you testing your code?
- Is the url white-listed in config.xml? See: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html
- Don't forget that you must run this after the onDeviceReady event.

Try this:

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.youtube.com','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=Return');"
```

You probably do not need to `return true` in the onClick event.